# Transferência de preços entre loja virtual e página externa

Tags: javascript, java, html, api, google-maps

Quero criar uma loja virtual utilizando soluções já disponíveis como Shopify ou Iluria. Só que o serviço (entregas) não teria uma precificação fixa, o preço seria baseado na localização do remetente e do destinatário. Para isso, gostaria de usar uma página externa que integrada com o GMaps faria o cálculo do preço baseado no trajeto e transferiria esse preço para a loja virtual afim de direcionar o cliente para o checkout e pagamento. 
É possível fazê-lo usando essas soluções ou só criando uma loja do zero?
É viável utilizar essa página de cotação com o API de uma empresa de pagamentos (Stone, Mundipagg, Paypal) para redirecionar diretamente para o checkout? 
Em termos de viabilidade, incluo aí segurança também.

Comment: Acho que você está pedindo um monte de coisas e de forma bem ampla e genérica. A resposta a sua pergunta daria para escrever um livro.

Comment: Desculpe, é que eu sou muito amador e fiquei com bastante dúvida, até na hora de redigir a pergunta. O ponto base da pergunta é: é possível realizar a integração entre uma página externa que realize a cotação e faça a transferência do valor cotado pra uma loja virtual como Iluria com segurança ou só criando uma loja do zero?